# Failed to create Maven Project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I added maven plugin in my eclipse .. but still can't create Maven project (doesn't exist in new project ) and i can't find it also in window -> preferences .. can any one tell me what's wrong please !?

Comment: To help, more info is required. what version of eclipse are you using? what version/which maven plugin are you using? How did you install the plugin?

Comment: Anything in the `workspace/.metadata/log` file?

Comment: i have eclipse helios , maven plugin m2e , i installed through help --> install new software an then added the url of the plugin "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"

Comment: @rlegendi: i searched in the log file and just found the messages that eclipse was publishing to me while installing the m2e plugin like this :
"!MESSAGE Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)" 
and other messages

Comment: i'm wondering if it is a jdk or jre problem .. could it be ?!

Comment: No, I think it is clrearly not a JRE/JDK problem. Try reinstalling m2e, but I believe this is a configuration issue and you could get a better support at their site/mailing list.

Comment: well i want to thank u all for ur responses before everything , about trying to reinstall m2e i already did that and eclipse show me a message telling that i can't do that because it is already installed :/
 can u give me their site or mailing list please :) and thank u again

Comment: See http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/support/

Answer (score 0):

May be Maven Integration (m2e) plugin not installed properly(check the eclipse version & try to install suitable plugin).

Alternately you could create maven project via command,

For core java project,

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

For Webapplication,

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Kindly refer the below link:

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/

Comment: Yeah, but then you must use mvn eclipse:eclipse to be able to use it with Eclipse, which I'd discourage, it's kind of PITA to live this way (you must regenerate the descriptors all the time etc.). I believe the solution would be a proper installation of the m2e plugin.

Comment: Without **mvn eclipse:eclipse** command , You could import the mvn command created project as Maven project instead of normal project import. Then this project would be same as you creating from eclipse maven project.

Comment: Nope :-) Eclipse does not supports Maven projects by default, you need the Eclipse-Maven integration plugin installed. *There is no Maven project by default in Eclipse if that plugin is not installed.* And yes, I was also suggesting using the m2e Eclipse plugin *instead of* the Maven Eclipse plugin (maven:maven), which is a bit problemmatic to use.